# Grouping notifications by type in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure for `notifications` table.

```
id  user_id post_id type    status  date       seconduser_id
1   1       23      1       0       somedate   4
2   2       25      2       0       somedate   3
3   3       26      1       0       somedate   4
4   4       28      2       1       somedate   5
5   5       21      2       0       somedate   4
---
---
and so on
```

Here `type = 1` means a `like` and `type = 2` means a `comment`. `status = 0` means `seconduser_id` hasn't seen the notification yet. `seconduser_id` is the notification recipient.

Is it possible to get notifications for 1 user (example `seconduser_id = 4`), with notification grouped by `type`, showing `count` and the latest `user_id` for each `type` (**in one query**)?

The implementation of this would be something like ***User3 and 10 other people liked your post.***

*Edit: So far I have something that pulls all notification for `user 4` and then groups in php. I don't think this is efficient and so am looking for better solutions.*

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Could you add expected result as example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is an aggregation query.  The complication is getting the latest user id for each type.  THere is one method, using `substirng_index()`/`group_concat()`:

```
select type, count(*),
       substring_index(group_concat(user_id order by id desc), ',', 1) as latest_user
from notifications n
where secondaryuser_id = 4 and status = 0
group by type;
```

I am not sure if you also want to filter by `status`.

Edit (added by OP):

Using the above code and grouping by both `post_id` and `type`. Because you want to say ***User1 and 10 others liked your post***. Which means for each grouped notification, `post_id` has to be unique.

```
SELECT *, substring_index(group_concat(user_id order by id desc), ',', 1) as latest_user, COUNT(post_id) AS total
FROM notifications n
WHERE seconduser_id = 4 and status = 0
GROUP BY post_id, type
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have modified your answer slightly to make it more practical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(user_id) AS LatestUser, type, COUNT(type) AS total
FROM notifications
WHERE seconduser_id = 4
GROUP BY type
```